# How to create a previous pointer in a linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have created a LinkedList class that has a function for deleting the first element in the list and one that deletes the last element in the list.  The first one is easy, after I delete the element, I set it to point to the next element.  Works great.  However, when I delete the last element, I have to point it to the previous element in the list which becomes the last at that point.  I cannot figure out how to do this.  Please advise.  Here is the code:

```
    void LinkedList::pop_front()
{
    mFront->data = NULL;
    mFront = mFront->next;
}
```

How can I get a function to delete the last element but reset the tail to point to the new tail?

```
void LinkedList::pop_back()
{
mBack->data = NULL;
...
}

class LinkedList
{
    public:

        // Default Constructor
        // Purpose: Initializes an empty list
        // Parameters: none
        // Returns: none
        LinkedList();

        // The push_front function
        // Purpose: add an item to the front of the list
        // Parameters: a int item for the front
        // Returns: none        
        void push_front(int data);

        // The push_back function
        // Purpose: insert an item into the back of the list
        // Parameters: int item to add the the back
        // Returns: none                
        void push_back(int data);

        // The pop_front function
        // Purpose: delete the item in the front of the list
        // Parameters: none
        // Returns: none
        void pop_front();

        // the pop_back function
        // Purpose: remove the item at the end of the list
        // Parameters: none
        // Returns: none        
        void pop_back();

        // The getFirst function
        // Purpose: print the first item in the list
        // Parameters: none
        // Returns: none
        void getFirst();

        // the GetLast function
        // Purpose: return the last item in the list
        // Parameters: none
        // Returns: none
        void getLast();

        void printList();

        // the clear function
        // Purpose: clear the list, free memory
        // Parameters: none
        // Returns: none
        void clear();

        // Destructor
        // Purpose: clear up memory
        // Parameters: none
        // Returns: none
        ~LinkedList();

    private:

            LinkedList *mFront; //  point to the front of our list
            LinkedList *mBack; // point to the back of our list
            LinkedList *next;  // the next node
            LinkedList *previous; // the previous node
            int data;  // our list data manipulator
```

Comment: If you want O(1) removal of elements, you'll need a [doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) (i.e. `next` and `prev` pointers on all nodes).

Comment: If this is homework, it is a good idea to add the `homework` tag so that people can try to give more explanations and less code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singly linked lists do not offer O(1) deletion of the last element. You'll have to run through the whole list from the start to find the second-to-last element.

```
Node* i = mFront;
while ( i->next != mBack ) i = i->next;
mBack = i;
```

Comment: it says Node is undefined.  I am a beginner, do I need to reference a data member of the class there?  Or, create a new pointer?  I edited the code above to show my class name and data members.

Answer (score 1):

If the list isn't double linked, you'll have to start at the first element to find the last one:

```
void LinkedList::pop_back()
{
   mBack->data = NULL;
   current = mFront;
   do{
      current = current->next
   } while ( current->next );
   mBack = current;
}
```

**Very important** - since `data` appears to be a pointer, you're possibly running into a memory leak. Just setting `data = NULL` doesn't free the memory, you'll have to explicitly delete it:

```
delete mFront->data;
```

Comment: Your code also gives me errors.  I am not sure what current is referencing, I changed the code above to represent my class